# How to use python and windows com in pyramid (threads)?

Tags: python, multithreading, com, pyramid

I'm connecting to MS Word by win32com.client.Distpatch function and on the second request i've got error: 'CoInitialize has not been called.'
I've found this topic:

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t328097-coinitialize-error-when-using-adodbapi.html

and got that I have to call of CoInitialize in new thread.
So question is where to call CoInitialize function in pyramid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So i added call of CoInitialize in function:

```
@subscriber(NewRequest)
def new_request_subscriber(event):
    import pythoncom
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
```

and works without exception.