# 'CoInitialize has not been called' When call a function with parameters by Object

Tags: python

I am trying to call a ExecutionStart function by the Object `TestSessionProjectObj`. When i pass and try to print the object it shows the below error `CoIntilaization`.

> File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
>       self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
>   File"C:/AI/AutomationDesk/API/Scripting_Python/MITETestSessionProjectExecution.py", line 52, in ExecutionStart

```
print TestSessionProjectObj.Name
```

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 529, in **getattr**

```
ret = self._oleobj_.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1)
```

> com_error: (-2147221008, 'CoInitialize has not been called.', None, None)

Answer (score 4):

Just try by adding this :

```
import pythoncom

pythoncom.CoInitialize()

.....
```

Comment: Ok, it should solve the problem. But an explaination about the *why*  would make it a better answer. Currently it is not far from a comment...

Comment: which place we call the pythoncom.CoInitialize() in starting or end level or middle level